# Why are naturally occuring liquids more rare than solids and gasses on Earth?

Tags: phase, intermolecular-forces, dipole

There are only a few naturally occurring liquids I can think of on earth, such as water, mercury and animal oils.

## **Why are naturally occuring liquids more rare than solids and gasses on Earth?**

#### To be specific,

- By Earth I mean the surface which is inhabited by humans, not the interior core or mantle.
- I am referring to **naturally occurring substances**, i.e. naturally occurring liquids are far more rare than naturally occurring gasses or solids. Why is this?
- I am referring to average **conditions of temperature and pressure that prevail on our planet's surface**, not man-made conditions or extremities.

### Current Line of Thought

I looked into inter-molecular forces for an answer. Here's what I've come up with.

At Earth's temperature, substances held by **dipole-dipole forces** are solid and substances held together by weaker **london forces** are liquids or gasses, such as oils or noble gasses.

The majority of substances have dipole-dipole interactions, hence are solids. In comparison, london forces are weaker so require only a little energy to change phase, which is why non-polar and noble-gasses are gasses or liquids at the same temperature. However, the majority of substances or not noble gasses or non-polar, which is why solids are more common on Earth.

**To sum, dipole-dipole are the most common inter-molecular forces. Substances with dipole-dipole forces are solids at earth's temperature, hence the majority of substances are solids.**

I am aware that many exceptions arise to this general trend, such as water, however the fact remains that liquids are more rare than solids and gasses on Earth.

I still have a feeling I am wrong, **so if anyone could provide a better answer** or critique on my line of thought that would be great.

*Updated the question with specifics to make it less broad*

Comment: Comments moved to http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39043/discussion-on-question-by-g-gip-why-are-naturally-occuring-liquids-more-rare-th.  Please do not have extended discussions in the comments.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your argument misses two major points.

First, a great number of solids are *ionic* and *metallic* substances. Those show a really strong bonding mechanism between elementar particles.

And second, to get your theory to work, you have to take into account the *size* of molecules. To evaporate or melt anything, you have to break or at least disturb all the bonds each molecule has to its surroundings.

For something as small as H2O, not even hydrogen bonding is strong enough to make it solid. A large molecule like Polyethylene, on the other hand, is only held by weak London forces, but has melting points as high as 145°C, and cannot be evaporated.

Comment: I'm primarily after an answer to the main question of the article `why are liquids more rare than solids or gasses on earth`, so I can then understand better as to why I'm wrong. 

Do you know the answer to the main question? If so, please edit to include it.

Comment: I'm not sure how your point relates to why natural liquids are more rare than solids and gasses. `First, almost all ionic and metallic substances are solid.` Yes, but aren't liquids still more rare than solids and gasses on Earth? Apologies If I misunderstood.

Comment: I just wanted to point out hat you've overlooked a large part of all solids in your argument. And are you talking about compounds in general or elements? For the latter: I'd say they are all solid, unless they have very good reason to be gaseous. Plus the two oddballs mercury and bromium.

Comment: Related (albeit remotely): http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/41971/at-what-temperature-in-kelvin-are-most-of-the-elements-on-the-periodic-table-l

Comment: Hi Karl. Thanks for the response. I'm generally speaking about both naturally occurring elements and naturally occurring compounds, ones commonly seen in nature. But yes, that's precisely my point! Most are solid, with the exception of oddballs like mercury and bromium. My question is why is this the case? On colder planets like Jupiter you have methane seas. **What is the molecular reason for most elements being  solid or gas, rather than liquid, in the conditions of temperature and pressure that prevail on our planet's surface?**

Comment: The reason for your confusion is that you generalise. If you look at individual classes of substances (metals, ionic compounds, diatomic elements, ...), there are very clear trends with the molecular weight, polarity, etc of those substances, perfectly understandable for every high school kid. There is however no general theory for everything.

Comment: Is it then the case that there is lots of separate reasons for most elements being solid or gas, rather than liquid, in the conditions of temperature and pressure that prevail on our planet's surface, rather than a general single reason? For example, when you state *"For the latter: I'd say they are all solid, unless they have very good reason to be gaseous"*, is it lots of separate reasons and not general reason for this behaviour? 

I presumed there would be a general reason as this question was posed in an education chemistry video.

Comment: Indeed there is no general reason. Heavy particles tend to be solids. Nonpolar substances are gaseous, unless they're too heavy. Metals are solid. Polar substances are liquids, unless they're in fact not very polar (ammonium, carbon monooxide), or have a relatively low melting point, depending on molar weight. Ionic substances are solid. And so on. There are exceptions, but they only slightly bend the rules, not break them. If you look closer, everything starts to make sense.